# IBM MobileFirst - Native Android Application adding push manifest permissions

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am confused about the permissions section for IBM's MobileFirst GMS Push notifications found here. (Section 5)

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/notifications/push-notification-native-android-applications/

I have added all of these permissions verbatim, but im getting an error saying i havn't added manifest permissions. Do i need to modify the package names in these permissions?

Is this activity built in?

```
<activity
android:name="com.worklight.androidnativepush.AndroidNativePush"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Here is the error logcat

```
07-25 23:24:48.285  17146-17146/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp, PID: 17146 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp/com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.push.PushActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your manifest is not allowed to work with push. Android Manifest Error: Missing permission in manifest: com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your manifest is not allowed to work with push. Android Manifest Error: Missing permission in manifest: com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE 
        at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush.<init>(WLPush.java:180) 
        at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.getPush(WLClient.java:957) 
        at com.companyname.hitch.mobilefirsttestapp.push.PushActivity.onCreate(PushActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why don't you include the error you're getting as well as your manifest file?

Comment: Hey Idan, working on it. Its on a separate workstation. One moment

Answer (score 0):

When creating a MobileFirst-based Hybrid app with the Android environment, MobileFirst will be creating it based on a template with a set of predefined permissions and activities.

In a native application, you are the one creating it. MobileFirst only supplies you with the SDK and a set of integration instructions.

The activity that you mentioned in the question (taken from the tutorial page) is the activity of the sample application included in the tutorial. In your own app's AndroidManifest.xml you will see your app's name instead of "androidnativepush" (or rather need to create it).

Make sure not to use "androidnativepush" anywhere unless that is your app name.

Comment: It looks like the 'category' tag inside the intent filter in the receiver is using the "com.worklight.androidnativepush". I'm assuming this needs to be changed as well with my package name?

Comment: Yes. Anywhere it is says "androidnativepush" should be replaced with your own app name. I edited the tutorial to clarify this.